# Maya Python: Make Playblast and export it to the folder "movies" in my set project

Tags: python, maya

I'm trying to make a `playblast` by just making one single button on my UI, when you click on it, it exports the playblast with all the settings already setup, but now I want to export the playblast on the "movies" that is on my set Project.

I tried to make a `path = cmds.workspace (query=True, dir=True)` but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the filerule of your project to find your movie location, here is an example to find the cache location if it has been set in your project :

```
workspace = cmds.workspace(fileRuleEntry='fileCache')
directory = cmds.workspace(en=workspace )
```

You should be abe to replace fileCache by your movie entry (I don't remember the spelling for movies inside the maya project)

Comment: it doesnt' seem to work when I try to put on my movies folder, also I'm trying to make an incremental button so it doesn't overwrite the files, etc.

Comment: the incremental thing is something you can do with os module. Parsing the folder and find the incrementation. Playblast command can filled then with the path of playblast you will be generating. As for the fileRule of your 'movies' or images' in your Project Window